# Jsoup to post data and parse alternative URLs on CFscript

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, cfml, coldfusion-11

I need to get and parse a page from `primary_URL` using Jsoup in CFscript.

If page status is not OK or data is corrupt or empty, I should try an alternative page from `secondary_URL`.

`primary_URL` accepts POST requests only and I don't know how do it in cfscript

`secondary_URL` accepts GET by default

This is an idea:

```
<cfscript>
jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
response = jsoup.connect(primary_URL).userAgent("#CGI.Http_User_Agent#").timeout(10000).method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();  // How to use Method.POST in this case???
if(response.statusCode() == 200)
{
    doc = response.parse();
    theData = doc.select("div##data");
    ...
    `some other parsing and SQL UPDATE routine`
}
else
{
    response = jsoup.connect(secondary_URL).userAgent("#CGI.Http_User_Agent#").timeout(10000).execute();  // default is GET
    if(response.statusCode() == 200)
    {
        doc = response.parse();
        theData = doc.select("div##same_data");
        ...
        `some other parsing and SQL UPDATE routine`
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

How to jump to the `secondary_URL` in case the response is OK but the data appears to be currupt or empty? A kind of `goto` operator?

Running ColdFusion 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to jump to the secondary_URL in case the response is OK but the data appears to be currupt or empty? A kind of goto operator?

Instead of checking the statusCode only, call a function. Inside this function perform all necessary checks (corrupted data, empty data ...).

```
<cfscript>

    function IsValid(response) {
       // Perform all the tests here...
       // Return TRUE on success or FALSE otherwise

       return true;
    }

    jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
    response = jsoup //
                 .connect(primary_URL) //
                 .userAgent("#CGI.Http_User_Agent#") //
                 .timeout(10000) //
                 .post();  // Simply call the post() method for posting...
    if( IsValid(response) ) {

    } else {
        response = jsoup //
                    .connect(secondary_URL) //
                    .userAgent("#CGI.Http_User_Agent#") //
                    .timeout(10000) //
                    .get();  // Make your intent clear

        if ( IsValid(response) ) {
            // ...
        }
    }

</cfscript>
```